# how to modify google maps navigator control style

Tags: google-maps, navigation

i search through the google maps api reference, but they provide no method or property for creating a new type of navigation control. i wonder how to create navigator control like image below.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. First [disable the defaultUI](http://code.google.com/intl/el-GR/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/controls.html#DefaultUI)
2. Add your custom control in the map like [that](http://code.google.com/intl/el-GR/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/controls.html#Adding_Controls_to_the_Map)
3. Catch zoom events from the map(zoom_changed event) and notify your control and vice versa(map.setZoom())

Comment: links are broken Disable UI https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-disableUI     custom controls https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-custom?hl=fr